theoretical question - is it possible to distribute fractions of an NFT instead of individual tokens?
I'm considering this problem:
Let's say I have a couple of NFTs.  They're very, very valuable, with values ranging from a thousand dollars to a million dollars.
I'd like to use these NFTs to fund some big projects - more explicitly, to pay the people working on these projects (a bridge, a school, a highway, anything, regardless of feasibility).
How can I distribute these NFTs in a way that they can be used to pay people (divided into smaller arbitrary amounts) while remaining traceable?
I could sell them immediately and convert them into eth or fiat currency, but then they'd be more difficult to trace (allowing some corrupt managers to take all the money for themselves, for example).
Is there a way to fractionalize an NFT arbitrarily?  For example, give away 7.8% today, 12% tomorrow, etc.
I could also mint a whole bunch of ERC20 tokens when the ERC721 contract is created, but that would create astronomical gas prices (dividing a $1 million nft into 1 billion one-cent pieces would be insane).
How could I solve this problem?

Yes - and I think there might be a little confusion on what tokens are.
Please note, there are likely several approaches you could take to do this.
Idea 1 | DAO-ify
What you could do, is have the owner of the NFT be a governance contract, like one from Openzeppelin, and have the DAO operated by token voters of the DAO, for example, using a Governance Token. Then, as you sell these tokens, people with ownership can have decision making power into what to do with the NFT. You can learn more about how to do this in the Cyfrin Updraft DAO curriculum. Disclosure: I am lead instructor of Cyfrin Updraft.
You said:

dividing a $1 million nft into 1 billion one-cent pieces would be insane

But it really wouldn't be very gas-expensive at all. People would only pay for gas costs of the token on purchase. You could mint the 1 billion tokens in a single transaction, all it really does it change a single storage slot in the contract -> the total supply.
This is essentially the same as distributing fractions of the NFT, I feel like you might be thinking that a "token" is more than it really is. A token is just a smart contract with a very gas-efficient mapping data structure that says how much of the token different addresses own. So, even if you didn't use a token, you'd still have to have this mapping, and it would basically be a token anyway.
Idea 2 | Multi-sig
There could also be a situation where you have the owner of the NFT be a multi-sig, and you sell spots on the multi-sig. This would only be feasible if you had a small number of buyers, this would be insanely gas intensive to have a multi-sig that required 1,000 people to sign.
It would be pretty straightforward to setup a Safe Multi-Sig, make it a 5 out of 9, and sell as many slots as you'd feel comfortable with.
Conclusion
There are a lot of ways you can do this, but the most straightforward way will be to use tokens, which, is essentially just a mapping data structure in the NFT smart contract.

Very detailed answer. Upvoting it.

Thank you so much!  I've been confused about DAOs for a while, too.  Will check it out!
